# How to get return value of different functions in a for loop with multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm currently making some numerical solver for current simulation. To make my code faster, I made a function that returns the result of elementwise matrix multiplication, and gradient... and so on.

```
    def mmul(A, B, procname, return_dict):
        return_dict[procname] = np.multiply(A,B)
    def mgrad(A, procname, return_dict):
        return_dict[procname] = np.gradient(A/dx)
    def madd(A, B, procname, return_dict):
        return_dict[procname] = A+B
```

Now here's the body of the code. I first made a dictionary(return_dict) and store the results for each processing units, and get the values(Vgrad, Pgrad, Psquare) from the dictionary.

```
    for k in range(0,max_iter-1, 1):
        #0. Firstly generate all of the auxiliay calculation arrays 
        post_V, post_p, Vij_coeff = np.zeros((3, lx, ly), dtype = float)

        # Calculate carrier density of the next step
        processes = []
        #----------------------------                                 # Const/mtx for calculating p
        manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
        return_dict = manager.dict()
        p0 = multiprocessing.Process(target = mgrad, args = (V, Vgrad, return_dict))
        processes.append(p0)
        p0.start()
        p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target = mgrad, args = (p, Pgrad, return_dict))
        processes.append(p1);p1.start()
        p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target = mmul, args = (p,p, Psquare, return_dict))
        processes.append(p2);p2.start()
        for process in processes:
            process.join()
        Vgrad = return_dict['Vgrad']
        Pgrad = return_dict['Pgrad']
        Psquare = return_dict['Psquare']
```

However, this code makes the error below

```
    PicklingError: Can't pickle <function mgrad at 0x000002776C3614C8>: it's not the same object as __main__.mgrad
```

Is there any solutions to get the calculated value of the function, while running in multiprocessor?

Comment: Where is `mgrad` defined?  That is, I see the code for it above, but is that code in a different module than the code defining the Process objects?  Given that everything you're doing (except for `p0.__module__ = "__main__"`, which I don't understand) seems very garden variety, I'm wondering if the location of your target functions might have something to do with the error.

Comment: mgrad is defined in a different cell in my jupyter notebook.  Please ignore p0.__module__='main' (I got the same error before i wrote this in my code).

Comment: My guess is that that your problem has something to do with the way Jupyter has things set up.  Can you try moving the mgrad and the other functions in with the main process code?

Comment: Sorry about the late reply. That gives me a 'broken pipe' error. now i'm trying to fix this with queue..